# Audio output to HDMI and no other option available

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, output

It was working fine and then something appeared on screen with thre options and i accidentally clicked on headphones , then the output window in setting only displayed built-in-headphone and i restarted, then it showed dummy output and now it shows HDMI/DisplayPort-Built-in-Audio and no other option, bluetooth headphones work fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.